# javascript createElement table adding unwanted tbody

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm using a mixture of plain-jane JavaScript and Jquery to dynamically create a table. I use a for loop to iterate through the data returned from an Ajax call, but it isn't creating new rows. So I output the html using an alert, and I can see there's quite a mix up of table elements, including a tbody that shows up, even though I'm not explicitly creating a tbody.

Ajax code, where on "done", I create a table:

```
function performSearch(){
    var q = $("input[name='search']").val();
    var url = "performsearch.php";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "post",
        data: { 'q' : q },
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data) {
        /* the table creating part of the code - something wrong in here */
        var output = $("#output");
        var table = document.createElement("table");
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        var button = document.createElement("button");
        output.append( $(table) );
        $(table).append( $(tr) );
        $(tr).append( $(td).attr("colspan","100%") );
        $(td).append( $(button).attr("type","button").on("click",function() {
                 exportOutput(data);
             }).html("Export"));

        $(table).append("<tr>\n"); // I'm clearly adding a tr tag, but it doesn't show up
        $(table).append("   <th>id</th>\n");
        $(table).append("   <th>processed thru</th>\n");
        $(table).append("</tr>"); //ending the tr tag

        for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){ //let's say only one record is returned
            $(table).append("<tr>\n"); //clearly adding a tr tag, but it's not showing up
            $(table).append("   <td>"+data[i]['id']+"</td>\n");
            $(table).append("   <td>"+data[i]['processed_thru']+"</td>\n");
            $(table).append("</tr>\n");
        }
    }).
    fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + jqXHR + ", " + textStatus );
    });
}
```

Here's the html it's producing:

```
<table>
    <tbody>  <!-- look at tbody tag, where'd it come from? -->
    <tr><td colspan="100%"><button type="button">Export</button></td></tr>
    <tr></tr> <!-- look at this extra tr tag, where'd it come from? -->
    <tr></tr>\n\ <!-- look at this extra tr tag, where'd it come from? -->
    </tbody>\n\ <!-- I didn't add this -->
    <th>id</th> <!-- th tag not wrapped in a tr tag -->
    <th>processed thru</th>
    <th>status</th>
    <td>1568</td> <!-- td tags not wrapped in row tag -->
    <td>06/03/2016</td>
    <td>ACTIVE</td> <!-- no tr tag following the end of the td tags -->
</table>
```

Comment: Part of your code creates elements correctly, and part doesn't. Half way down, you switch to using HTML, but you do it incorrectly. The DOM isn't a string.

Comment: @squint Ah, I see what you're talking about. I'll fix, and report back.

Comment: If `<table>` is rendered by browser, the browser by default will add a `<tbody>` by default. A `<table>` without a `<tbody>` is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the comments and used them to whittle the code down to using all DOM methods of creating content, with only one string used to define an iframe style. Many code lines have been trimmed as a result:

```
function performSearch(){
    var q = $("input[name='search']").val();
    var url = "performsearch.php";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "post",
        data: { 'q' : q },
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data) {
        $("#output").html('');
        var output = $("#output");
        var table = document.createElement("table");
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        var button = document.createElement("button");
        var row = table.insertRow(0);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        $(cell1).attr("colspan","100%");
        $(cell1).append( $(button).attr("type","button").attr("name","export").on("click",function() {
                 exportOutput(data);
             }).html("Export"));
        var row2 = table.insertRow(1);
        var headerString = "id,processed_thru,document_number_j,status,case_number,name_of_court,file_date,date_of_entry,expiration_date,amount_due,interest_rate,plaintiff,defendant,mailed";
        var headerArray = headerString.split(",");
        for(i=0;i<headerArray.length;i++){
            row2.insertCell(i).outerHTML = "<th>"+headerArray[i]+"</th>";
        }

        for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            var dataRow = table.insertRow(i + 2);
            for(ii=headerArray.length - 1;ii>-1;ii--){
                dataRow.insertCell(i).outerHTML = "<td>"+data[i][headerArray[ii]]+"</td>";
            }
        }

        var inlineStyle = document.createElement("style");
        inlineStyle.innerHTML = "#iframe{ display:none; width:10px;height:10px;border:#f00 1px solid; }\n";
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        iframe.setAttribute("id","iframe");

        //finally, stitch all the pieces together inside of the output div:
        output.append(inlineStyle);
        output.append(iframe);
        output.append(table);

    }).
    fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + jqXHR + ", " + textStatus );
    });
}
```

Comment: If this is an exercise in mixing cocktail of programming styles then it is interesting. FYI: Table DOM has a number of specific methods like `table.insertRow`, `table.createTHead`, `row.insertCell` to list few.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev I'll explore suggestions. Believe me, I'd rather not have mixed this cocktail. Originally I constructed the table entirely using a concatenated string, but the problem came when trying to pass the returned data object to another function using the button, which was also made within the string. Finally I had to make the button, and its parent td, tr, and table, using the DOM methods. But I failed at writing the rest of the table, specifically the rows in the FOR loop, using the DOM method, so I resorted to writing a new table as a string. That was easy and straightforward.

Comment: Programming "cocktail" (mostly) eliminated in answer. Thanks!